# pgpool-II for Postgres - Is it what I need?

Tags: postgresql, database-cluster

I just stumbled upon pgpool-II in my search for clustering my Postgres DB (just getting ready to deploy a web app in a couple months). I still have the shakes from excitement, but I'm nervous, as each time I find something this excellent I am soon let down. Have you any experience with pgpool-II, and will it help me run my database in multiple VMs, and later in multiple physical servers altogether? Is it all I need for backing up, load balancing, and providing a higher availability for my DB server!?

Also, is it easy to use the parallel query function (for instance, in Django or through Pythons psycopg2)? This would be most excellent for providing reporting and aggregation!

One last thing: It seems to work between Postgres and psycopg2. Is this a correct understanding of it, so I can use psycopg2 the same as normal, without regard for pgpool-II?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pgpool-II works fine for what it claims to do.  And it fits between your application and the database the way you expect it to; just point psycopg2 toward it instead of directly at the database and off you go.

The main thing you have to note is that while it supports many different types of features--replication, load balancing, parallel query--you can't use them all at once.  It sounds like you may be under the impression you can do that, and it doesn't work that way.  The documentation is not all that clear on this subject (the English version at least, I can't speak to the original Japanese one).

For example, if you run pgpool-II in its "Master/Slave" mode, so that it supports load-balancing for scaling reads, you have to use another program to actually do the replication between those nodes.  Slony was the supported replication solution to put underneath of there in earlier PostgreSQL versions, as of pgpool-II 3.0 and PostgreSQL 9.0 you can also use the soon to be released Streaming Replication/Hot Standby features of that new version as well.

pgpool-II is a useful component and you can use it in a lot of interesting ways, but I doubt it will be "all you need" for every requirement you hope to achieve with it.

Comment: Japanese? lol, my name is "orokusaki" because of The Shredder from Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles :) Great answer, btw. Thanks!

Comment: Hi,what's the performance of the PGPOOL?   Do you use pgpool in product database ?